# ImageView ("headbar") different screens etc

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I just want to make an ImageView as my headbar ... it should just fill out his parent linear-layout.. apparently it does not.

is there any way to tell the scaleType just to fit its parent-layout? (best solution in XML) i saw the was a programming-solution which setting the scaleType to "fill" ... but there seems to be no matching xml-attribute, or didn't i see it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/linearlayoutmain">
    <ImageView
         android:layout_marginTop="0dp" 
         android:src="@drawable/headbar" 
         android:id="@+id/mainheadbar" 
         android:scaleType="fitStart"
         android:paddingTop="0dp"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:layout_below="@id/linearlayoutmain">
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

any thoughts/solutions about it? I thought i don't need to mind about the aspect ratio because I 9patched the whole thing.. so it shouldn't mind.

edit: it seems to work better when i use an ImageBUtton instead of an imageview... however, i got problems on lower -size screens... they seem to don't mind my 9patching... lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use three types of layouts in general

1. layout-hdpi
2. layout-mdpi
3. layout-ldpi

Also you need to use three values layouts in general

1. values-hdpi
2. values-mdpi
3. values-ldpi

Here i explain for LDPI Device Header you have to do for all you device HDPI,MDPI, etc

For example simple xml that has Image as Header : layout-ldpi - Header

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"  android:layout_height="50px"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
 
  <ImageView    android:id="@+id/header_main_title" android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="50dip" 
                android:background="@drawable/header_image" 
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_marginRight="10dip" 
                 />
```

Similarly values-ldpi contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <resources>
     <style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowTitleSize">50px</item>
      <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/WindowTitleBackground
       </item>      
     </style>
   </resources>
```

Similarly for Styles.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="WindowTitleBackground" parent="android:WindowTitleBackground">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

In your Manifest.xml include this Line :

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/vmi_icon" android:label="@string/app_name"  android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
```

Put the Styles.xml and Themes.xml inside of **values-ldpi** folder

I shown Header for ldpi device similarly you need to create for **MDPI** and **HDPI** device

changes should be made in this line of all

if it's HDPI :

```
<item name="android:windowTitleSize">100px</item>
```

If it's Mdpi :

```
<item name="android:windowTitleSize">70px</item>
```

Similarly for header.xml :

if it's HDPI :

```
android:layout_height="100px"
```

If it's Mdpi :

```
android:layout_height="70px"
```

Comment: thanks at the first place.. maybe you can help me with my second question too.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030772/9patching-cant-have-more-than-one-marked-region-along-edge